# Do we have a StackStorm pack for gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was looking for a tool to auto-trigger actions based on certain rules and I came across StackStorm. I mainly want to use it with GCP, like publishing a message in pub/sub or execute certain actions based on certain value changes in datastore.
I see a pack for AWS, but I didn't find anything specifically for GCP in stackstorm exchange. Is there any pack that I can use for GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was requested in in March 2019 here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/magic-modules/issues/1480.
It is still `Open` with this comment:

> Sadly, we don't have enough bandwidth to take this on. If you'd like to submit PRs, we'd be happy to merge them in.